# Send Whatsapp attachment using PHP

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

Is there a way that I can send a **whatsapp** attachment using PHP or a Laravel package?

And is it official `API`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would need permission to access the intended server for this type of work involving a third-party application. If granted, the next thing is to send a request based on your need and the given API options. 
I could find [CHAT-API](https://github.com/lucassmacedo/whatsapp-chat-api) through a quick search specifically designed to manipulate data for WhatsApp. You need to establish your initial connection, then register your number and follow the instructions in the Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write a wrapper for the web interface! There's no API!

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please help me with any info?

Comment: A wrapper is a tool that extracts data from another data source, in this case the web interface of Whatsapp. That's the only solution to use Whatsapp on your own page. P.S.: I've searched for a wrapper and found [this](https://github.com/xaamin/whatsapi), but no promises that it's really useful.

Comment: I can do that using PHP?

Comment: Of course. Read about web scraping with PHP or use the API I linked above!

Comment: you didnt link anything yet

Comment: Look, in the comment above! there's a link. But I link it [again](https://github.com/xaamin/whatsapi)

Comment: So you told him there is no API, and say he should write a wrapper for the web interface and the link you post is for an laravel wrapper of an unofficial api? Btw. if you don't use laravel, use the chat-api and not the wrapper.. https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

Comment: I meant no official API. Of course if you write a wrapper it's quite useful to write an API as well!

Comment: You can use WhatsApp Business API to send attachments, it's an official api from WhatsAPP https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media/#upload